# Why would the sendgrid node.js api hang when sending an email and give no error?

Tags: sendgrid, remix.run

I am trying to send an email with sendgrid in a remix action. I have verified that the api key is the correct environment variable. Nothing is being logged to the console at alll. Here is my code:

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_KEY);
  const message = {
    from: "admin@chriswestbrook.com",
    to: "westbchris+blog@gmail.com",
    subject: `a comment has been left on ${slug}`,
    text: "testing",
    html: `author:${author}<br/>
    email:${email}<br/>
    text:${text}
    `,
  };
  try {
    await sgMail.send(message);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: In your code, a successful request would not trigger a log of any sort. So it looks like it's correct and succeeding? Have you gone through the [domain authentication process](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) for `chriswestbrook.com`?

Comment: I have gone through that process and it says it was verified. I tried logging right after the send call and it never logs, I can see in the terminal the post request never returns anything, I think it is waiting for the sendgrid process to finish.

Comment: Is that all the code that you're running or is there more code around it in context? If there is more code in the file, can you share it too? And what version of Node are you using to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up having something to do with their indy stack using msw to mock server api requests blocking sendgrid. See this [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/indie-stack/issues/84).

Comment: I have same issue at this moment, do you know the way to fix it?